# Meteor callback on window.open(url) does not open window

Tags: javascript, url, callback, window, meteor

I would be glad if someone knew why `window.open()` does not work within callbacks of `Meteor.call()`. You can easily reproduce this by calling `window.open(url)` in a callback of a `Meteor.call('method',argument,callback(e,r){...})` on the client. Outside of the callback it works, and inside the callback, `window.location = url` properly redirects.

I have some secured urls from filepicker.io in my database. Since it's inefficient to generate all the policies and signatures in advance, I want to generate them in the click event when someone actually tries to retrieve those files. Unfortunately, within the client callback of the `Meteor.call('methodname',param,callback(e,r){...})`, the `window.open(url)` does not seem to work and I am clueless why.

**Template**

```
<template name="upload">
  <div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical">
    {{#each files}}
      <button id="fp" class="btn btn-primary">{{filename}}</button>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>
```

**client/client.js**

```
Template.upload.files=function(){
    return files.find({});
}
Template.upload.events({
  'click #fp':function(){
    // window.open(this.url)
    // if I uncomment the above line, a new window
    // opens with the unsigned url
    // (this.url is a valid mongo cursor)
    Meteor.call('signedUrl',this.url,function(err,result){ // result is signed url
      console.log(result); // loggs the correct url in the console
      // window.location = result;
      // if uncommented, the line above redirects correctly 
      window.open(result); // does NOT open the new window with the signed url
    });
  }
});
```

**server/server.js**

```
Meteor.methods({
  signedUrl: function(url) {
    // some proven-to-work-code that you can find at
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546676
    console.log(signed_url); // loggs the correctly signed url on the server
    return signed_url;
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance for any hint! Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its likely this is being caught by chrome/safari's anti popup filter.

You probably want to use the new window in a non malicious way, but modern browsers need user input to be able to open a new window. In a callback there isn't a user input 'trigger', so the browser might think its a popup/ad.

There really isn't much of a way to get passed this. You could create a new button when the callback is run, then ask the user to click it to open a new window.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I also thought of popup-blockers first, but can this really be the reason since the new window pops up without trouble when called outside the callback?

Comment: Yeah because outside the callback you would be triggering it with some kind of UI action (clicking, entering, etc) to make that happen, you make it trigger using some kind of user input. Inside the callback its sort of on its own (similar to how the ad popups come, as soon as the script runs, or on its own after a while without any user UI trigger). The callbacks don't count when they're linked to a user action because this could be abused (i.e load the page, wait a bit for the callback in a timer or something then fire the popup - most ads used to do this)

Comment: Yeah of course, thanks. That makes totally sense, still a bit sad though ;)